# Jayanthi Determination of Gurus

Tags: puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita

Yesterday (25th April 2023),was Sri Ramanujar Jayanthi (Chithirai Thiruvadhirai) and Sri Sankara Jayanthi (Vaishaka Panchami).

Why is the birth of one Guru based on Star and the other Guru based on Thithi? Can anyone please tell

Comment: Because Tamil Nadu focuses more on the nakshatra due to following the solar calendar. Same thing happens in the case of Janmashtami

Comment: @Adiyarkku can you please explain a little more in detail.

Comment: It’s too detailed to explain in writing

Comment: @Adiyarkku, can you write whatever that is sufficient for the question? Not very detail. Just giving the important things alone.

Comment: Okay, very brief. So, panchang comprises 5 parts which include nakshatra and tithi. Usually 90% of the times, the same nakshatra is supposed to come on the same tithi. So for example if at Bhagavan’s birth time it was Ashtami tithi in Bhadrapada Krishna paksha and Rohini was the nakshatra, usually every Janmashtami should somewhat overlap with Rohini nakshatra. North India and south India follow the panchang, so fir determining the dates, the tithi is determined (distance between sun and moon) and the nakshatra is also mentioned. Since we have the correct dates which roughly correspond to .1.

Comment: The same nakshatra as well eg Janmashtami as given above, there’s no separate need to go only as per nakshatra. On the other hand, Tamil Nadu and Kerala follow started following the solar calendar which means rather than their months depending on how far the sun is from the moon (tithi) it depends on when the sun enters a particular zodiac/ rashi -  365 days calendar. Solar and normal panchang calendar are not in sync. When using the solar calendar, the question therefore arises how ro determine Janmashtami. Tithi not used, dates used so unlike panchang, using the tithi is not an option .2.

Comment: Therefore we need some way where the sky is similar to as it was during real Janmashtami, that reflects the true picture. Best way without disturbing the dates calendar, is to follow nakshatra. So if North India celebrates Janmashtami on Ashtami tithi, and Rohini happens to be the nakshatra cool, TN will be celebrating on the same day. If not, then TN will celebrate a day later when Rohini nakshatra actually comes. Now coming to your question, Shankaracharya was a pan India figure and is the main person in north India which uses panchang. Therefore his birth is as per tithi. Ramanujar on  .3.

Comment: The other hand is primarily a Tamil Acharya, though he has a huge following even in the north. Accordingly, even north India while respecting the Tamil traditions uses the Nakshatra to determine his birth. That’s why one Acharya as per tithi and one as per nakshatra .4.